# How to get the current element under Bootstrap Affix?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to get the offset of a sibling of the current affixed element. Is this possible? I was hoping to use something like:

```js
$('.affixed').affix({
    offset: {
        top: 150,
        bottom: function() {
            return $(this).siblings('p').offset().top;
        }
    }
});
```

But `this` is just a `{top:X, bottom:Y}` object and not the actual element. I have multiple `.affixed` elements that I need to affix dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

The `bottom` and `top` functions will pass through the original element that initialized the collection.

For multiple elements, you'll have to wrap `affix` in `each` from the original collection.

```js
$('.affixed').each(function() {
    $(this).affix({
        offset: {
            top: 150,
            bottom: function(e) {
                return $(e).siblings('p').offset().top;
            }
        }
    });
});
```